# Calculating the frictional force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction

Here's my problem and the work I've done.   The time is already past for me to submit the answer, but I want to know where I went wrong and why I was wrong.

The 2-kg box slides down a vertical wall while you push on it at a 45 degree angle from below. Both the box and the wall are wood. What magnitude of force should you apply to cause the box to slide down at a constant speed?

The coefficient of kinetic friction for wood-wood is 0.2.

The vertical forces acting on the box are:

$F_{box}$(sin 45) - $F_{friction} - mg$ = 0

where

$F_{box}$ = force acting on the box

$F_{friction}$ = frictional force opposing the motion

$m$ = mass of the box

$g$ = acceleration due to gravity

Hence

$F_{friction} = F_{box}$(sin 45) - $mg$ --- call this Equation 1

The normal force acting on the box is as follows:

$F_{box}$(cos 45) = $F_n$

and since

$F_{friction}$ = µ$F_n$, then

$F_{friction}$ = µ($F_{box}$)cos 45 --- call this Equation 2

Setting Equation 1 = Equation 2,

$F_{box}$(cos 45) - $mg$ = µ($F_{box}$)cos 45

Simplifying the above for "$F_{box}$"

$F_{box}$(cos 45) - $F_{box}$(µ*cos 45) = $mg$

$F_{box}$(sin 45 - µcos 45) = $mg$

and solving for "$F_{box}$"

$F_{box}$ = $\frac{mg}{cos 45 - µcos 45}$

Substituting appropriate values and calculating for "$F_{box}$"

$F_{box}$ = 34.65N

The system says that the solution is 23N.   How did they get that and where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box is sliding vertically down at constant speed after overcoming your force F **and** friction, so the equation of forces in vertical direction should be

$mg = F_{box}(sin 45) + F_{friction} $

Repeat your calculation with the above equation, then you will get the correct answer.

Comment: Damn, I looked at the problem and made the same mistake as Tyler :-)

Comment: thanks a lot.   I wouldn't have seen that otherwise.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Decide on which way is your positive direction.

Assuming that the positive (+ y) direction is upward. 
Then your F(g) is negative.

Since the y-component of F(T) points upward, boom!
     There you have another vector pointing upward. + F(T)*sin(45)

F(Kinetic Fr) also points upward as it opposes the downward motion. + F(K.Fr)

Sum of the forces in the y-direction =

```
      - F(g) + F(Kinetic Friction) + F(T)*sin(45) = 0  //Constant velocity
                                                             a = 0 m/s^2
```

F(T) = F(g) - F(Kinetic fr) / sin(45)

F(T) = mg - μ mg /sin(45)   Also, = mg(1 - μ)/ sin(45)

F(T) = 2.0 kg * 9.81 m/s^2 (1 - 0.200) / sin(45) = 22.197 N

//Make sure your calculator is not in Radian mode.

..
..
..
I'm not sure why it's 23 N for my homework too. 
P.s I know I kinda dragged the steps too long but hopefully someone is able to 
    understand.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post.

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se]! Note that we're [not really a homework help site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/). I don't think there's any harm in posting a solution to a question from five years ago, when what we accepted was a little different, but nowadays complete answer like this one tend to get removed in favor of more conceptual discussions.